# Prolog, testing labeling heuristics

Tags: prolog, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

I'm working on some experiments for comparing different labeling heuristics in Sicstus Prolog.

But I keep getting into 'Resource error: insufficient memory'.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in my testcode.

The following code will replicate my problem:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).

atest( R, C ):-
    X is R * C,
    length( M, X),
    domain( M, 0, X),
    all_distinct( M ),

    statistics(walltime, [_,_SinceLast]),
    labeling( [],M ),
    statistics(walltime, [_,SinceLast]),

    write('Labeling time: '), write(SinceLast),write('ms'),nl.


% Testcode for looping through alot of variations and run one test for each variant
t1:-
    Cm = 1000,
    Cr = 1000,
    (
    for(C,0, Cm),
    param([Cm,Cr])
    do
        (
        for(R, 0, Cr ),
        param([C])
        do
            atest( C, R )
        )
    ).
```

A short time after I call the t1 predicate, I get a 'Resource error: insufficient memory' exception.

I guess I should do something after I call atest to release resources?

Also: Is this the correct way to measure labeling-time? Any better way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to measure? The time to find the first solution, or the time to label through all solutions? Currently you do neither nor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything strictly wrong, but you are trying to run

```
length(Xs,N), domain(Xs,0,N), all_distinct(Xs), labeling([],Xs).
```

for N up to 1000000.  The system constructs a search tree with depth N, and has to store intermediate states of the variables and the constraint system for each level.  This takes a lot of memory for large N, and it is quite possible that you get a memory overflow already for a *single* run with large N.

The second issue is that you are running your benchmarks in a recursive loop, i.e. you are effectively creating a *conjunction*

```
atest(0,0), ..., atest(1000,1000)
```

and since each call to atest/2 succeeds with its first solution and keeps its search state around, this means you are trying to create a search tree with 250500250000 levels...

The simplest improvement is to cut each search after the first solution by changing your code to `once(atest(C,R))`.  A further improvement is to run the benchmarks in a *failure-driven loop*

```
(
    between(0,Cm,C),
    between(0,Cr,R), 
    once(atest(C,R)),
    fail
;
    true
)
```

which will free memory sooner and faster, and reduce distortion of your measurements due to garbage collection.

Comment: Tnx. This solved my problem. I also trimcore/0 before fail/0 which looks like it helps further to reclaim used memory.

Answer (score 1):

### Toplevel hides alternate answers

If you are testing `t1` on SICStus' toplevel shell with some smaller values you might get the wrong impression that `t1` has exactly one answer/solution. However, this is not the case! So the toplevel hides from you the other answers. This is a special behavior in the SICStus toplevel which does not show further answers if the query does not contain variables. But there is a total of x! many solutions for your labeling, x! *for each* test case and the timing for the other solutions is some random value. You are out of memory because for each test case, Prolog keeps a record to continue producing the next solution for each test case.

### Looping

I do not recommend using a failure driven loop for testing, instead, use the following loop which is very similar but much safer:

```
\+ (
      between(0, Cm, C),
      between(0, Cr, R),
      \+ atest(C, R)
   ).
```

The big difference to a failure driven loop is when `atest/2` accidentally fails for some `C` and `R`.  In a failure driven loop this will go essentially unnoticed, whereas above construct will fail.

Some systems provide a predicate `forall/2` for this purpose.

### Timing

If you do timing, better only use the *first* element of the list and compute the difference:

```
statistics(walltime, [T0|_]),
Goal,
statistics(walltime, [T1|_]),
D is T1 - T0.
```

In this manner alternate answers to Goal will give you a more meaningful value.